# Ошибка при сборке libusb c/c++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, libusb

> C:\Users\usr\Desktop\tests_cpp>***g++ un_05.cpp -L. -lusb-1.0***
>   C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfnETc8.o:un_05.cpp:(.text+0x24):
>   ***undefined reference to `libusb_init@4'*** C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfnETc8.o:un_05.cpp:(.text+0x6e):
>   ***undefined reference to`libusb_get_device_list@8'*** collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

когда я скачал библиотеку там были только 
1) файл include\libusb.h
2) файлы для mingw64\mingw32 \libusb-1.0.a

и на с++ и на c одна и та же ошибка

подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: попробуйте обернуть инклюд `libusb.h` в `extern "C" {`

Comment: к сожалению не дало результата

Comment: @VengeanceOftheghosts а как вы собираете то?

Comment: я положил файл libusb.h и libusb-1.0.a в ту же директорию где и компилируемый файл.cpp и как можно увидеть прилинковал его в g++

Comment: причем я использую типы данных из этой библиотеки и на них он ошибку не выдает

Comment: Типы данных и вообще без `libusb-1.0.a` бы работали. Где вы взяли .a, сами скомпилировали? Обычно таинственные undefined reference на MinGW бывают от несовпадения разрядности библиотеки и компилятора.

Comment: libusb-1.0.a уже был скомпилирован и находился в одной из папок библиотеки, разрядность я проверял, брал этот файл для mingw32, но там были ошибки уже к компилятору

Comment: Я бы все-таки еще раз проверил. *"были ошибки уже к компилятору"* Что за ошибки?

Comment: C:\Users\unreal\Desktop\tests_cpp>g++ un_05.cpp -L. -lusb-1.0
./libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-core.o):core.c:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
./libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-core.o):core.c:(.text+0x76d): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
./libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-windows_nt_common.o):windows_nt_common.c:(.text+0x9e4): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
./libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-windows_usbdk.o):windows_usbdk.c:(.text+0x1314): undefined reference to `__ms_vsnprintf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: как я понимаю это он ругается на .a файл из-за разрядности

Comment: Проверил, в пакетах MSYS2 есть libusb. Может проще оттуда поставите? *"как я понимаю это он ругается на .a файл из-за разрядности"* Чтобы не гадать, скажите разрядность компилятора (`cout << sizeof(void*)` что печатает?) и где взяли две разных `libusb-1.0.a` (там же должно быть подписано, какая для какой разрядности).

Comment: да, там было подписано для какой разрядности я взял для 64,на запрос cout << sizeof(void*) печатает 4

Comment: Ну так значит ваш компилятор под 32 бита, и библиотека должна быть под 32. Она может называться "i686" или что-то в этом духе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка был а в разрядности компилятора и в том что я не положил dll файлы в папку с main.cpp

Что сделать чтобы избежать данной ошибки:

1)следует проверить разрядность скомпилировав:

> cout << sizeof(void*);

если 4 - 32 битная
если 8 - 64 битная

2) Далее нужно взять подходящие файлы из библиотеки и перенести их к main.cpp

3) При компиляции прилинкуйте только lib___.a файл

В mingw (g++) на примере файла libusb.a:

> g++ main.cpp -L. -lusb